# Error in NodeJs Column 'state' cannot be null

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, ejs

I don't know where I'm going wrong please help me resolve this issue. In my SQL table I have mentioned not null for all the columns. I'm attaching herewith my routes.js code :

> Here's my routes.js code

```
const {
   con,
   sessionStore
 } = require('./config/db');
exports.new = function(req, res){
    message = '';
   if(req.method == "POST"){
      const post  = req.body;
      const username= post.username;
      const title= post.title;
      const state= post.state;
      const category= post.category;
      const description= post.description;
 
      if (!req.files)
                return res.status(400).send('No files were uploaded.');
 
      const file = req.files.uploaded_image;
      var img_name=file.name;
 
         if(file.mimetype == "image/jpeg" ||file.mimetype == "image/png"||file.mimetype == "image/gif" ){
                                 
              file.mv('public/imgs/uploads/'+file.name, function(err) {
                             
               var sql = "INSERT INTO `nt_data`(`username`,`title`,`state`,`category`, `images` ,`description`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)";
               var query = con.query(sql, [username, title, state, category, img_name, description], function(err) {
                  console.log(err)
                 if (!err) {
                   res.redirect('show/' + username);
                 }
                 else {
                  message = "This format is not allowed , please upload file with '.png','.gif','.jpg'";
                  res.render('new.ejs',{message: message});
                }
               }); 
            }); 
          
   } 
}
   else {
      res.render('new');
   }
 
};

exports.show = function(req, res){
    let message = '';
    var username = req.params.username;
    const sql="SELECT * FROM `nt_data` WHERE `username`='"+username+"'"; 
    con.query(sql, function(err, result){
      if(result.length <= 0)
      message = "show not found!";
      
      res.render('show.ejs',{data:result, message: message});
   });
};
```

Please help me fix this issue any help would be highly appreciable.
Thnak you

Comment: Do you get the right values from req.body?

What is the type of column 'state'?

Remove the column 'state' from your table and your query to see if the problem persists.

Comment: If I remove column state then the same problem shifts to category column

Comment: Then it means you have a problem with either your table or the post data itself. Check if the data is correct in the req.body

Comment: yes the data is correct here